# SpotDL on Django

Tags: python, django, spotify

I am trying to create a Django project on [SpotDL](https://github.com/spotDL/spotify-downloader). Here's my files:

--urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admins/', admin.site.urls),
path('spdl/', views.spdl),
```

]

--views.py

```
def spdl(request):
import spotdl
spotify_url = "https://open.spotify.com/track/2Cd9iWfcOpGDHLz6tVA3G4";
subprocess.run(['spotdl', spotify_url] , check=True)

return HttpResponse("downloaded")
```

It successfully downloads the track on my PC. But, I want to customize it a little bit. I want to set the `--bitrate` on views.py file during the spotdl call. I tried this line but failed: (got via ChatGPT)

```
subprocess.run(['spotdl', '--bitrate', '128', spotify_url], check=True)
```

How can I pass other commands to SpotDL like `--bitrate` or `--cookie-file cookies.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can make calls to the binary and pass command line arguments using the subprocess call, attaching the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) document for your reference.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./a.out', '--name=yash', '--age=22', '--job=dev'])
```

I have tested on this c++ code and its working as expected. Similar can be done by calling spot-dl. Please make sure spot-dl is on path and can be accessed by the server.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    string name = argv[1];
    string age = argv[2];
    string job = argv[3];
    cout << "Hello" << name << "! You are " << age << " years old and work as a " << job;
}
```

**Sidenote**

- doing it on scale will be a very bad idea.